# Microsoft graph API: Query to get list of subscriptions already created on mailbox for a specific user using userID

Tags: c#, graph, microsoft-graph-api

Is there any way to get list of subscriptions specific to a users mailbox like we have one for user's one-drive similar to the code below.

The is one end point available to fetch out all the subscriptions as https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
but I want to get only mailbox specific subscriptions.

```
IDriveItemSubscriptionsCollectionPage subscriptions = await graphClient.Users[{UserId}]
                                                                               .Drive
                                                                               .Root
                                                                               .Subscriptions
                                                                               .Request()
                                                                               .GetAsync();
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reaching out. To my knowledge, there isn't currently a way to do this with MS Graph, since [listing the subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) doesn't support the OData query params. As a workaround, I would suggest fetching the list then filtering by the `resource` param client side once the response is sent by graph:

> /users/{UserId}/messages

Would you consider [filing a feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) on the M365 developer platform so this can be looked into?